# Is it possible to use ‘dein’ in a letter to non-significant others?

Tags: word-usage, valediction

A common German valediction at the end of emails or letters is *dein/e*, e.g:

> Dein Luli.

In my language, this is only used for one’s boyfriend or girlfriend. Is it acceptable to use that valediction for other people, i.e. non-romantic friends in German?

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I really don’t get what you’re asking from the way you’re wording your question: *dein* is a possessive pronoun second person singular. I have voted to close as *unclear.* Please [edit] your question to clarify its meaning. Learn more about closing and editing in the [help].

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer. I also cleaned up the tags; 90 % had no connection to the question whatsoever. As an aside: Which is your language?

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely nothing wrong in German with using the valediction *dein* for anybody who you would address using the more informal *du* second person pronoun. It can be used towards the significant other, good friends, not-so good friends, family and even colleagues (assuming that *Sie* is not standard at your workplace).

When a letter or email is addressed to more than one person, one would use *euer* instead. And if you use the formal second person pronoun *Sie* but still want to indicate some sort of closeness, using *Ihr …* is also fine.

While a certain degree of closeness is associated with this type of valediction (i.e. you wouldn’t use *Ihr* if writing to a bank) there are much more intimate valedictions available.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, *dein/e* can indeed be used in the suggested context.

In practice, this valediction seems to have largely fallen out of use at least among the younger generations. I exchange plenty of (electronic, but following the same form for written content as physical) letters, and I think I have never seen the valediction *dein/e* in that context, while *(viele/liebe/herzliche) Grüße*, *bis bald*, and plenty others are commonly used.

There is indeed one class of letters that routinely uses *Ihr/e*. Those are usually advertisements whose (alleged) senders try to force a sense of familiarity onto the recipient. Still, they are not trying to insinuate a romantic relationship.

Answer (score 0):

"Dein" is used with people one is "close to." This includes, but is not limited to, significant others. It would normally be used to one's children (one might address parents, teachers, or other "older" people as Sie), but close friends would also be addressed as "du" or "dein."

Comment: "one would address parents as Sie": really? Ich kann es kaum glauben.

Comment: @TonyK: That was true of people my age (59). Maybe you come from a different generation.

Comment: Well, you say your parents aren't German, and I can believe that some governesses insisted on 'Sie'. But parents? Even 50 years ago?

Comment: @TonyK: On the one hand, I agree with you, on the other hand, I know of instances where parents were rederred to as *Herr Vater* and *Frau Mutter*, respectively, although that does not necessarily imply also using *Sie*.